# Latex problem with indentation

Tags: indentation, algorithms, algpseudocode

During writing an algorithm using Latex syntax I encountered indentation problem that procedures started in one place and ended in another.
Part of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Test}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\State $\textit{currentS} \gets \textit{initialS}$
\State $\textit{bestS} \gets \textit{currentS}$
\State $\textit{listTest} \gets \left[ \right]$
\While{$fitness(bestS) < 0$}{
\State $\textit{bestC} \gets \textit{null}$
\For {($\textit{ca} \in \textit{currentS.get})}${
\If{($\neg\textit{listTest.contains(c)})$}{
\EndIf}
\EndFor}
\EndWhile}
\State \Return  $\textit{bestSolution}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You're misusing the tool: the syntax for `\While` is

```latex
\While {<condition>}
...
\EndWhile
```

with no braces around the contents of the loop.

Full code (I added a `\State` in the inner `\If`); note also that `\mathit` is preferable to `\textit`. For the null array I changed `\left[\right]` into `[\,]`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Test}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\State $\mathit{currentS} \gets \mathit{initialS}$
\State $\mathit{bestS} \gets \mathit{currentS}$
\State $\mathit{listTest} \gets [\,]$
\While{$\mathit{fitness}(\mathit{bestS}) < 0$}
  \State $\mathit{bestC} \gets \mathit{null}$
  \For {($\mathit{ca} \in \mathit{currentS.get})}$
    \If{($\neg\mathit{listTest.contains(c)})$}
      \State do something
    \EndIf
  \EndFor
\EndWhile
\State \Return  $\mathit{bestSolution}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I came to the same conclusions